# Select one item with specific id then add to that everything else in alphabetical order

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I have mySQL DB where I have this: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gse45vsk6jo4wts/dbSelect.PNG)
I need to return result where first item will be item with **id==1** and then add to that everything else in alphabetical order. This is what I want:
[Názov predmetu], [Algoritmizácia úloh], [Fyzika 1]...

Now Im using this:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT nazov FROM tbPredmety ORDER BY nazov ASC");
    echo "<select name='subject_name'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<option value = '" . $row[nazov] . "'>" . $row[nazov] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: can you provide the actual result if your code and what you want it to look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `CASE` clause inside your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT nazov 

FROM tbPredmety 

ORDER BY 
   -- item(s) with item_id 1 will appear first 
   CASE WHEN item_id = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
   nazov ASC
```

I used `THEN 0 ELSE 1` but for your purpose you could use any pair of values in which the former value is considered less than the latter value when sorting.

EDIT: For mysql you may need to use `CASE ... END CASE`. If the above does not work try changing **END** to **END CASE**.